# Sending "request payload" with libcurl?

Tags: c++, request, httprequest, libcurl, google-chrome-devtools

I am using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se). I know how to send form data. I want, however, to send a *"request payload"*, but I have no idea how to.

This is what an example of what I am trying to do, in Chrome Developer Tools: [View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myR22.png)

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line version of what you want would be something akin to:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"data":"blob"}' http://address.com
```

(you'll probably want to include cookie information for authentication too)

I don't know how well that translates to libcurl, but that's the essence sending a [request payload](http://www.w3.org/TR/di-gloss/#def-http-payload-entity) with curl.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question is, what's the difference between this and sending form data? Is it just the same thing, without the "x=y" format?

Comment: Thanks, I found my answer, which I posted below. Enjoy the bounty in a bit.