# Replicate request payload with cURL, PHP

Tags: php, curl, payload

There is a website that when you fill some form, it send a xhr request with some content of the form in the payload header. The content is similar to this one (not exactly this, this one was extracted from another website, but the same format of content separated with pipes):

```
7|0|5|https://www.bosscapital.com/app/Basic/|B8CC86B6E3BFEAF758DE5845F8EBEA08|com.optionfair.client.common.services.TradingService|getAssetDailyTicks|J|1|2|3|4|2|5|5|CB|U9mc4GQ|
```

I want to replicate this request with cURL but I don't know how to do it. I don't know the name of the input fields (because the have no name in the HTML code and I can't find the request on the JS).

I was looking at some Stack Oveflow treads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805748/how-to-upload-file-via-request-payload-using-curl-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950691/how-to-send-request-payload-with-php-curl) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292997/sending-request-payload-with-libcurl), but still is not clear for me how to do it.

Hope you can help.

P.D.: I know how to use cURL, but I din't even know this Request Payload thing before this job was assigned to me.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use Postman to run your call (or see the curl version)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

with the interceptor to catch the XHR request https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo